# How to Turn note pad files to C#?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm creating a character controller script in unity. I have the source code written in note pad but I can't figure out how to transfer the code to a C# file. I'm wondering how to turn Note pad to c#?

Comment: You mean you can't just copy/paste?

Comment: Rename the extension from **.txt** or whatever the current extension is to **.cs** then drag it to your project. Unity should recognize and compile it if there is no error.

Comment: I'd second copy-pasting, but would also suggest that in the future, you should develop the code in Unity's C# editor instead of Notepad in the first place.  It's a purpose-built environment, and you'll discover it has numerous advantages over a generic text-editor when you're developing code.

Answer (score 1):

If the file contains valid C# code, save it with an extension of `.cs`.  If you've already saved the file, you can rename it, removing `.txt` from its end and adding `.cs` in its place.

It's probably worth using an integrated development environment for editing C#, though - they will make developing much easier and faster.  The most common one for C# is Visual Studio, but there are other options as well, such as VS Code or MonoDevelop.